# Facing issue in lightning component managed package after upgrade where property name removed

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, lightning-experience

I'm facing the issue. I have the lightning component managed package which includes 2 design properties on page builder.

1. first property name title (string type)
2. 2nd property name help (String type)

It's work fine I have created the managed package **version 1.0** and test in my test org. I add the component on the home page and I see it its work perfectly.

**Problem:**

Now I remove the 2nd property name **help (String type)** from my component and upload the package create the new **version v2.0**  and send push upgrade to my test org where I have installed version**1.0** after successfully upgrade I notice my component is not showing on the home page.

**Workaround:**

if I edit the page layout and save it again then the component shown.
but I don't want to edit all pages. anybody experience this issue before and how to deal with this?